# Check if a value of an object of certain class has been altered

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I need to check if an object's element has been altered and change another value depending on it.

For Example:

```js
class myClass{
  constructor(value1, value2){
    this.value1 = value1
    this.value2 = value2
    this.values = {
      value1: this.value1,
      value2: this.value2
    }
  }
}

var myObject = new myClass(2,4)
console.log(myObject.value1, myObject.values)

myObject.value1++ // ou myObject.value1 = 3
//expected log 3 {"value1": 3, "value2": 4}
console.log(myObject.value1, myObject.values)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `myClass` instance to be single source of truth.

```js
class myClass{
  constructor(value1, value2){
    this.value1 = value1
    this.value2 = value2
    const container = this;
    
    this.values = {
      get value1() {
        return container.value1
      },
      get value2() {
        return container.value2
      }
    }
  }
}

var myObject = new myClass(2,4)
console.log(myObject.value1, myObject.values)

myObject.value1++ // ou myObject.value1 = 3
//expected log 3 {"value1": 3, "value2": 4}
console.log(myObject.value1, myObject.values)
```

Comment: Oh, i just tryed using `get value1(){return this.value1}`, i dint thought about using a vareable to be the `this`. Its so simply. Thanks!

Comment: @LuísHNrique `this` in getter will be `values` object it self so calling `this.value1` will basically cause StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to dynamically handle all properties of an object then you can use Proxy instead of separated setters and getters.

```js
class myClass{
  constructor(value1, value2){
    this.value1 = value1
    this.value2 = value2
    this.values = {
      value1: this.value1,
      value2: this.value2
    }
  }
}

var myObject = new myClass(2,4);

var proxied = new Proxy(myObject, {
  get(target, prop) {
    return Reflect.get(prop === "values" ? target : target.values, prop);
  },
  set(target, prop, value) {
    return Reflect.set(prop === "values" ? target : target.values, prop, value);
  }
});

proxied.value1++ // ou myObject.value1 = 3
proxied.value2 = 1000;
console.log("proxy", proxied);
```